# Yii - Ajax Get based on drop down selection

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am trying to display the price based on the selection of product from a drop down.

View contains:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
                    'id'=>'plan-form',
                    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
                )); ?>  

    <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'plan_id',
            $planList, array('id'=>'planid', 'prompt'=>'Select Plan',
            'ajax' => array('type'=>'GET',
            'url'=> Yii::app()->createUrl('mbr/plan/ajaxGetPrice'),
            'update'=>'#price'))); ?>

    <div id="price">0.00</div>    
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Action:

```
public function actionAjaxGetPrice()
{
    Yii::log("Within AjaxGetPrice");

    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        Yii::log("ajax request");
    else
        Yii::log("regular request");

    //$plan=Plan::model()->findByPk((int) $_GET['plan_id']);
    //Yii::log(serializ($plan));
    // echo $plan->price;

    echo "10";

    Yii::app()->end();      
}
```

It is not updating the price. Its not calling the action at all. I looked at the suggestions found in Yiiframework and here and tried those and still no luck.

when I add this to the view

```
    <?php
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
          "Get Price",
          Yii::app()->createUrl('mbr/plan/ajaxgetprice'),
          array( // ajaxOptions
            'type' => 'GET',
            'update' => '#price'),
          array( //htmlOptions
            'href' => Yii::app()->createUrl('mbr/plan/ajaxgetprice')
         )
        );
    ?>
```

I get the response when I click on the link, but it renders a separate page with value "10". I have URLFormat = Path.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how to do this the Yii way but the following javascript should be useful.

```
$("#yourdropdownidhere").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'your url here', //(dynamically generated by product item)
       type: "get",
       success: ajaxSuccessHandler
    });
});

function ajaxSuccessHandler(obj) {
    $('#price').html(obj);
}
```

I also suggest sending a JSON object as the response for AJAX requests, so it will have an actual structure.  A great blog post on this to check out would be [Fully ajax website with Yii](http://tpoxa.com/2011/04/19/fully-ajax-website-with-yii/)

Comment: Thank you, @Mikt25. I tried this before and it didn't work (I didn't have the URL correct). Thanks for the help. I have to set values in couple of places, so will definitely make it a JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this as shown

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('categories','', 
              $category,
              array('ajax'=>array('type'=>'POST','url'=>CController::createUrl('yourController/GetId'),'update' =>'#data'))
            );?>
```

yourController action

```
public function actionGetId(){
        echo 10;
    }
```

And the div

```
<div id="data">0.00</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it on the controller that renders the view. If you are using renderPartial assure that the processOutput() option is set to TRUE, otherwise Yii will not attach any Javascript.

If you use render instead of renderPartial it also works.